# How to trigger a bat file on remote server only after the pssession is formed on the server

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, net-use

```
Write-Host "Welcome to Application Process Start/Stop Dashboard" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "`n" "1) Stop" "`n" "2) Start"
[int]$resp = Read-Host "Choose option 1 or 2 for stopping or starting application process respectively"
if($resp -eq 1)
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Are you sure you want to STOP ?', "Info" , 4 )
if ($result -eq 'Yes') 
{
$user = "NAmarshmellow"
$server = "Desktop_10U"
$storesess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $user 
Enter-PSSession -Session $storesess
$path = "\\Users\mellow\Documents\Proj"
$pwd = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd)
$value = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)
NET USE $path /user:$user $value
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/C C:\Users\Desktop_10U\Documents\Some\Stop.bat" -Wait
Clear-Variable storesess
Exit-PSSession
}
}
```

I want to trigger a bat file which has some commands that will stop a specific application process. To stop this application process there are specific commands which requires triggering the cmd file on a network drive. So I have written a code which will form PSSession and after the PSSession is formed only then the `NET USE` command should run. If I first form the PSSession and then trigger the command manually fire the `NET USE`  command then it works fine. But when I trigger the code as a whole it doesn't run fine it throws below error.

```
NET : System error 1219 has occurred.
At line:18 char:1
+ NET USE $path /user:$user $value
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System error 1219 has occurred.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared 
resource and try again.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that [Enter-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession) only works via an *interactive* prompt. aka. You typing in commands into a prompt. A script/running everything together is **not** interactive (i.e. you can't start entering in commands into the middle of the running script).

The work around is to use [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) and place everything you want to perform in a script block. This way can be executed as non-interactive commands. e.g.:

```
....

$user = "NAmarshmellow"
$server = "Desktop_10U"
$path = "\\Users\mellow\Documents\Proj"
$pwd = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd)
$value = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)

$script = {
    $user = $Using:user
    $path = $Using:path
    $value = $Using:value

    NET USE $path /user:$user $value
    Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/C C:\Users\Desktop_10U\Documents\Some\Stop.bat" -Wait
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $user -ScriptBlock $script

....
```

Comment: Thank you your solution was apt!